# Android - On notification click open file and pressing back does not show app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent

I show a local notification after a file download complete

```
    String fileName = AppUtils.getFileNameFromUrlPath(download.getFile());
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext, channelId)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_fluxble_icon_primary)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setContentTitle("Download Complete")
            .setContentText(fileName);

    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(mContext);
    File file = new File(download.getFile());
    Intent intent = AppUtils.getOpenApp(mContext, file);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

On notification click i open/show that file either image/doc etc to user.

```
    public static Intent getOpenApp(Context context, File url) {
    Intent intent = null;
    try {
        Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", url);
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        if (url.toString().contains(".doc") || url.toString().contains(".docx")) {
            // Word document
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/msword");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".pdf")) {
            // PDF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".ppt") || url.toString().contains(".pptx")) {
            // Powerpoint file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".xls") || url.toString().contains(".xlsx")) {
            // Excel file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".zip")) {
            // ZIP file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/zip");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".rar")) {
            // RAR file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/x-rar-compressed");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".rtf")) {
            // RTF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/rtf");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".wav") || url.toString().contains(".mp3")) {
            // WAV audio file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "audio/x-wav");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".gif")) {
            // GIF file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/gif");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".jpg") || url.toString().contains(".jpeg") || url.toString().contains(".png")) {
            // JPG file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "image/jpeg");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".txt")) {
            // Text file
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
        } else if (url.toString().contains(".3gp") || url.toString().contains(".mpg") ||
                url.toString().contains(".mpeg") || url.toString().contains(".mpe") || url.toString().contains(".mp4") || url.toString().contains(".avi")) {
            // Video files
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
        } else {
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*");
        }
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
//            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        AppUtils.showSnackbar((Activity) context, "No application found which can open the file");
    }
    return intent;
}
```

Which is working fine. When i click on notification it shows image by Intent.ACTION_VIEW intent but when i click back button it does not get back to my app instead it gets to mobile desktop screen. My app gets in pause/minimize mode.

Comment: Post your manifest please

Comment: Also, the code you have posted doesn't actually call `startActivity()`. Please post the code that actually launches the `Intent` you've built here. Also, you've wrapped the `if..else` block in a `try/catch` but `ActivityNotFoundException` will only be thrown if you call `startActivity()`, which you aren't doing in this code block, therefore the `try/catch` is unnecessary.

Comment: @DavidWasser i am not launching activity actually it is a pending intent and that opens when user clicks on notification.

Comment: @DavidWasser Intent intent = AppUtils.getOpenApp(mContext, file);
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

Comment: You shouldn't post code in a comment. The formatting is gone and it is difficult to read and follow. You should edit your question and put the code in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is clear now what the problem is. You are building an `Intent` to view a document using implicit intent (ACTION = VIEW) and putting that in a `Notification`. When the user opens the `Notification` and taps on it, the `Intent` which you have constructed is launched. This **doesn't launch your app**, it launches whatever app the user needs to VIEW the file. Your app doesn't even need to be running.

When the users clicks BACK, it just goes to the HOME screen because your app didn't launch the viewer, Android did.

If you want the user to go BACK to your app, you need to do this in a different way. The `Notification` should launch YOUR app, and then YOUR app should launch the VIEWer app. Then, when the user goes BACK, he will see YOUR app.

Answer (score 0):

I hope the problem is lunch mode here are some descriptions
Using Android Manifest  tag with attribute android:launchMode.
Including Flags in the intent delivered to the startActivity().
This launchModes and its equivalent startActivity Flags allow us to define, how a new instance of an Activity is associated with the current Task and specifies the instruction for its launch in the given Task.

launchMode — standard: This is the default method of the Activity. Right now, new occurrence of the Activity is made and placed in the Task which began it by steering the goal to it. The Activity right now be started up numerous occasions, each occurrence can have a place with an alternate errand and one undertaking can have its different examples.

launchMode — singleTop | banner — FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP: This mode or banner delivers the very same conduct as the standard launchMode if the new Activity in not effectively present in the back stack as the top. On the off chance that it is available at the top, at that point it acts in an unexpected way. Right now, same Activity resumes with the call to its onNewIntentmethod.

launchMode — singleTask | banner — FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: If an Activity don't exist in a previously made Task, at that point it begins the Activity in another Task with Activity's new occurrence at the foundation of the Task's back stack, else the Task is presented with the Activity's last state reestablished and this Activity gets the new expectation in onNewIntent strategy. Just one example of the Activity can exist at once. Right now, Back catch is as yet ready to restore the client to the past Task's Activity.for more and detailed description here is the link https://www.codementor.io/@dancanyego/what-are-tasks-and-back-stack-in-android-1597ndgazb
Also refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: i know what launch modes are. can you please phrase your answer specifically about the above problem. As right now it is 'standard' launch mode so it should maintain app backstack and when it opens a new activity on pressing back button it should get back to app stack top activity.